# Flutter local notification unable to Navigate to another route on click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using [fluttter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), I initialized the plugins as per the instructions on the docs and it looks like this

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
        didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(ReceivedNotification(
            id: id, title: title, body: body, payload: payload));
      });
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification:(String payload) async {// this fires when notification is clicked
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
    }
    //this line below is not working but prints the payload fine
    await Navigator.push(mcontext, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(payload)),);
  });
```

The navigator inside onSelectNotifications isn't doing anyting, the line after that is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, nothing logged and noting happens, here is a work around that worked fine with me:
instead of using context to navigate use GlobalKey so replace:

```
Navigator.push(mcontext, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(payload)),);
```

with

```
navigatorKey.currentState.push(mcontext, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(payload)),);
```

but first you have to declare this key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");
```

and assign it to your app widget like that:

```
MaterialApp(
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
....
```

Comment: I had to modifify the fist step to:  navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NotificationPage(payload: payload),
        ),
      );  but it still working. Thanks!!